# MySQL Connector: parameters not being added

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

Looking at my query log for MySQL, I see my parameters aren't being added. Here's my code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ApplicationVariables.ConnectionString());
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    com.Connection = conn;
                    com.CommandText = String.Format(@"SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalViews
                                                      FROM pr_postreleaseviewslog AS prvl
                                                      WHERE prvl.dateCreated BETWEEN (@startDate) AND (@endDate) AND prvl.postreleaseID IN ({0})"
                                                      , ids);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    com.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@startDate", thisCampaign.Startdate));
                    com.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@endDate", endDate));

                    numViews = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Dispose();
                    com.Dispose();
                }
```

Looking at the query log, I see this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalViews
                                                      FROM pr_postreleaseviewslog AS prvl
                                                      WHERE prvl.dateCreated BETWEEN (@startDate) AND (@endDate) AND prvl.postreleaseID IN (1,2)
```

I've used the MySQL .NET connector on countless projects (I actually have a base class that takes care of opening these connections, and closing them with transactions, etc.). However, I took over this application, and here I am now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you resolve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value = "T1COM";
```

Comment: Hey there. I tried as you said, but instead of MySQLType.Int, I use MySQLType.DateTime since startDate is actually a .NET DateTime object.

Got this exception:
Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored

Comment: Maybe I wanted to do it to fast ;-) Try this one.

Comment: See my post below, not enough text in this box for it.

Comment: This worked for me when I used `mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar);`

Comment: Note that the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?variable", "...value...");` always works well.

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL clients, especially for MySql use "?" instead of "@".

Comment: MySQL allows ? and @ as of 1.0.7, I believe.